# A problem about a finite extension field

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

This is the problem:

> Suppose that $K$ is an infinite field and $E|K$ is an extension with degree $n>1$. Prove that the quotient group $E^*/K^*$ is infinite.

i assume that the quotient group $E^*|K^*$ is finite, for example it's elements are  $(b_1)k^*,...,(b_m)k^*$

also we can assume $E=K(a_1,a_2,...,a_n)$,

from linear algebra we know :
$E|K$ can't be written as the finite union of it's proper subspaces,if we consider it as a vector space on $K$.i want to reach a contradiction...

any hint is welcomed.

Comment: You can even assume $n=1$. (I mean $n$ the way you used it the second time.)

Comment: can u please give me a hint?what should i do
?

Comment: Do you agree that you can assume $E=K(a_1)$?

Comment: why $E=K(a_1)$?

Comment: Well, if $E$ is an extension of $K$, you can find a field $K(a_1) \subseteq E$ with $a_1 \not\in K$. Do you see why if you prove the result for $K(a_1)$ it automatically implies it for $E$?

Comment: by induction u mean?

Comment: No. Because there is an injective group homomorphism $(K[a_1])^{*}/K^{*} \to E^{*}/K^{*}$. If the first is infinite, so must the second be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is a set of coset representatives of $K^\ast$, then $E^\ast = \bigcup_{a\in A} aK^\ast$. Furthermore, $aK^\ast \cup \{0\}$ is the span of $a$ if we view $E$ as a vector space over $K$. Thus, we have that

$$
\bigcup_{a\in A} \operatorname{span}\{a\} = \bigcup_{a \in A} (aK^\ast \cup \{0\}) = E^\ast \cup \{0\} = E.
$$

Because $E \neq K$, $\operatorname{span}\{a\}$ must be a proper subspace of $E$. Because a vector space over an infinite field is not a finite union of proper subspaces, $A$ cannot be finite. Thus there is no finite set of coset representatives of $K^\ast$, so $E^\ast/K^\ast$ has infinite order.

Comment: Very well said, Bruce!

Answer (score 0):

Hint. Let $\alpha \in E-K$. Consider the elements $x + \alpha$, for $x \in K$